# sending mysql fetched array data inside an email

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email

i'm trying to send array data inside an email and can't get this thing to work.
here's the exact code.

```
$c = mysql_query("SELECT item,qty,price,uom FROM saleitems WHERE saleinvid = '222384' ");
$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "Invoice from company";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$message = 'Greetings,
    you are receiving this email as an invoice as follows:
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>UOM</td>
        </tr>
        ';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($c)){
$message .="<tr>";
$message .="<td>".$row['item']."</td>";
$message .="<td>".$row['qty']."</td>";
$message .="<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
$message .="<td>".$row['uom']."</td>";
$message .="</tr>";
}
$message .="</table>Thank You,COMPANY";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

the mail is sent but all i see is the table header row and the "Thank You, COMPANY" row, but no items in between. any help is greatly appreciated.
My email provider supports HTML messages

Comment: Are you sure your email provider supports html?

Comment: Firstly, remove "print" calls from the code.

Comment: Please check your query for errors of number of rows returned, and come back here and print your results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the call of print is not necessary, because this way `print` always returns 1 and it doesn't actually try to concat the $row[...] to your message.

Try it this way:

`$message .= "<td>" . $row["item"] . "</td>" ;`

**Edit:**
In the mail you can see the header of the table, this indicates that the problem isn't the formatting of the data. So the problem must be that the script doesn't run the `while` statement.

Please edit the `mysql_query` call to this:

```
$c = mysql_query("SELECT item,qty,price,uom FROM saleitems WHERE saleinvid = '222384' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

This would indicate to you if you have an error in your SQL query (e.g. misspelled table or field names).

Also try to execute your query directly in the MySQL command line to control if the result really got some records.